# Neo4j Cypher: Difference between shortestPath and allShortestpaths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My question is theoratical and is regarding the difference between `shortestPath` and `allshortestpaths` inbuilt functions in `Neo4j` when using Cypther

What is the underlying difference same between them in Neo4j. 
I see my shortestpath algorithm also returning multiple answers with varying  lenghts.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide an example?

Keep in mind that if you have multiple input records/rows, you will get a separate result from `shortestPath()` for each row, since Cypher operations operate per row.

With `shortestPath()`, your output rows should be <= the number of input rows (since rows where no path exists will be weeded out, and there should be at most one result per row).

With `allShortestPaths()`, your output rows may be greater than your input rows, depending on how many paths have the same length per input row.

Comment: I had the same question. I haven't noticed Neo4j docs talking about the fact that shortestPath() works like an array function: array of matches -> array of shortest paths.

Comment: It's not quite that...I'm working on a knowledge base article that talks about this more in depth. But basically the two things to keep in mind about Cypher are: 1. Operations generate result rows 2. Operations (excepting special cases like LIMIT and aggregation functions) operate per row. So if you have a MATCH that results in 5 rows, and you perform some subsequent MATCH, it will execute per row. Same for functions. Same for procedures. etc.

Comment: There's a knowledge base article that touches on this a bit [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/resetting-query-cardinality/).